# String-matching first n letters of two strings

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

So for a problem I'm facing I would like to know how long a sequence (starting from index 0) two strings are 'the same' - I think it'd be clearer to just give an example;

- I would like the method to return 4 if the two strings are "Yellowstone" and "Yelling" - meaning, the first 4 characters of the two strings match ("Yell")

Is there any more (time-)efficient way to go about this than to just iterate over the two words? Could I make use of some built-in method of some sort? (For my task I want to avoid importing any custom libs)

Comment: You could use `substring` method in the `String` class, accompanied along with looping

Comment: Right, thought about that too. Might just be the most fitting thing to do, thanks for the input!

Comment: Instead of `substring` you can use the `contains` method too, although can't say about the performance benefit, as the `contains` may itself loop through the `Strings`

Comment: Right, although contains seem to return a boolean and that's not really what I need either. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Re, "Is there any more time efficient way..."  More time efficient than O(1)?  If you don't check the first letters, then how can you possibly know whether the first letters match?  If the first letters match, and you don't check the second letters, then how can you possibly know whether the second letters match?, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the fastest approach would be to use **Binaray Search**, which will give you O(logn) complexity instead of O(n).
Here **n** is the length of smallest string.

The approach is simple in binary search. Look for similarity end for the index character in both the strings. For example if i is your index then check i+1 for dis-similarity character where character at i index is similar. And if that is the case break, return i as your answer. Or else keep on searching in sub-scope.

**Edit**

Adding function for better understanding.

```
int lengthOfFirstSimilarCharacters(String str1, String str2) {
    int strlen1 = str1.length();
    int strlen2 = str2.length();
    if(strlen1 > strlen2){
        return lengthOfFirstSimilarCharacters(str2,str1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen1-1;
    while(i<=j){
        int mid = i + (j-i)/2;
        if(str1.charAt(mid) == str2.charAt(mid)) {
            if(mid+1<strlen1 && str1.charAt(mid+1) != str2.charAt(mid+1)){
                return mid+1;
            }
            i = mid+1;
        }else{
            j = mid-1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not sure I understand the difference between that an just a linear search? You check at index i that they match, and then you check at i+1 that they match? That sounds like a linear search to me, sorry if I'm getting something wrong :)

Comment: As an example to illustrate: indexes 1 to 16 - you check at 8, if it's same, you check at 12, if it's not, you check 4; (let's assume it was same at 8) if it's same at 12, you check 14, if not, you check at 10; (let's assume it was not same at 12) if it's the same at 10, you check 13, if not, you check at 11; (let's assume it was not) you check at 11 - if it's the same, length of prefix is 11, if not, the length is 10. All in all - 4 checks instead of 11. You half the range every time, which leads to O(log n) time.

Comment: Ah, of course - that makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to iterate through both texts. Iterate through the smaller one and compare character at same index. break as and when you find a mismatch

```
String a ="Yellow";
String b= "Yelling";
String smaller = (a.length < b.length) ? a:b;
int ret =0;
for (index based on smaller ){
  compare character using charAt and if matching ret++, else break;
}
return ret;
```

//use charAt along with equalsIgnoreCase ifu want it to be case insensitive.
String.valueOf(a.charAt(index)).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(b.charAt(index)))

Answer (score 1):

**Correction:**

The answer by Sachin Chauhan is indeed correct and better at runtime (i.e. using binary search to search for the first difference).

I will leave my answer to allow for a simpler solution programmer-time, for the cases where the length is of no great influence (i.e. relatively short strings), but a simple solution would be preferable.

**Here is the original answer:**

As it's a simple loop, I doubt any inbuilt method will be much of a "programmer"-time improvement (and definitely not much of run-time improvement worth to mention).

For the record, I know of no such Java method (perhaps some external library, but you've stated you'd prefer to avoid them).

Reference code would be something along these lines, I'd imagine:

```
public int longestCommonPrefixLength(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s1 == null || s1.length() == 0 || s2 == null || s2.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int commonPrefixLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i)) {
            commonPrefixLength++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return commonPrefixLength;
}
```

As we see, with all the verbosity of Java and my "clarity" style, it's still just 18 lines of code. :)

Relaxing some clarity, you can even shorten the `for` to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()) && s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i); i++, commonPrefixLength++);
```

for 6 lines less.

To take it to the (correct) extreme:

```
public int longestCommonPrefixLength2(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1 == null || s1.length() == 0 || s2 == null || s2.length() == 0) return 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()) && s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i); i++);
    return i;
}
```

6 LOC :)

**Something curious, by the way:**

`String` class has `boolean regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)` method (which does internally pretty much the above up to a given `len`) - you could also iteratively increase `len` until it no longer returns true, but that would not be anywhere near same efficiency, of course.

Comment: That looks like a fine solution, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using Streams

```
    String s1 = "Yellow";
    String s2 = "Yelling";
    int limit = (s1.length() > s2.length() ? s2.length() : s1.length()) - 1;
    int ret = IntStream.range(0, limit)
                .filter(i -> s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i))
                .findFirst().orElse(-1);
    //-1 if the Strings are the same.
```

Comment: Calculating limit would be better using Math.min:
`int limit = Math.min(s1.length(),s2.length()) - 1;`
as in st2rseeker's answer

Comment: If you're not familiar with Streams, its worth noting that findFirst is a short-circuit call. As soon as a match is found, the "iteration" of the stream stops. You can see this by adding `.peek(1-> System.out.println(i)` between .range() and .filter().

Comment: Its absolutely true that this solution has O(n) complexity. However, it may be faster in application than the binary search for certain data. The binary search makes more accesses and comparisons, and is not tail-recursive in this implementation.
 You have Stream overhead in this solution: it would be faster (if less concise) if implemented in a simple loop as suggested by others. If efficiency is the priority, It would be wise to benchmark against  actual data before deciding on an algorithm. Encapsulating this code allows trading out implementations.